# How to get the GridView selected Column index

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

i am trying to get the Gridview selected column index from wpf program. i can get the selected row index but not the selected colum index

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a position to change `GridView` control to `DataGrid`, you can try the code given below to get the current column's display index of the `DataGrid` from code behind:

> dataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex

This `CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex` property of DataGrid basically gets or sets the display order of the column relative to the currently displayed columns. It provides you the zero-based position of the column as it is displayed in the associated DataGridView, or -1 if the band is not contained within a control.

Hope the information will be helpful for you ..

Regards

Debasis

Comment: thank's everyone but i found another solution for this. as i took the mouse position and horizontal scrolbar offset to find the column number using column actual width

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can get the value of a specific cell

```
Object obj = GetCell(3).Content;
                     string cellContent = String.Empty;
                     if (obj != null)
                     {
                         if (obj is TextBox)
                             cellContent = ((TextBox)(obj)).Text;
                         else
                             cellContent = ((TextBlock)(obj)).Text;
                      }




private DataGridCell GetCell(int column)
    {
        DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow();

        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

            // Try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized.
            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                // Now try to bring into view and retreive the cell.
                customDataGrid.UCdataGridView.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, customDataGrid.UCdataGridView.Columns[column]);
                cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            }
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

i hope it will helps you....

Comment: thank's everyone but i found another solution for this. as i took the mouse position and horizontal scrolbar offset to find the column number using column actual width.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
    string lbl_nam = (Label)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex].FindControl("Label_nam");
    string nam = lbl_nam.Text;
  }
```